# Possible to add bookmarks in Nemo (Cinnamon)?

Tags: filemanager, cinnamon

When using Unity, Nautilus (the file manager) had a nice way to bookmark folders.

This question is about Cinnamon's file manager, Nemo. I do not see any way to bookmark a folder. My folders go quite deep and I would like to avoid the constant navigation delay.

**Is there a way to add bookmarks in Nemo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to *Bookmarks* → *Add Bookmark* or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Good stuff. I see you can also drag-and-drop a folder onto the nav bar. I guess this is a recent enhancement because I could not do it in versions earlier than 20.04.